# Using variables in preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

i have following string in $subject variable

```
<p>{{headline}}</p>
```

And i have a variable`$headline="Hello World"`

As you guess i want to replace `{{headline}}` With `Hello World` using preg-replace.

Method must be dynamic, because it's just an example for `headline`.

Comment: Are you trying to create a templating system?

Comment: Yep. Something like that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$vars = array(
    'headline' => 'foo'
);

echo preg_replace_callback('/\{\{(\w+)\}\}/', function (array $m) use ($vars) {
    return $vars[$m[1]];
}, '<p>{{headline}}</p>');
```

You might really want to look into an existing templating system with a similar syntax but based on a proper parser though, like http://twig.sensiolabs.org. [Mustache](http://mustache.github.com) also basically already does the same thing.